# Installation of Ubuntu does not give options on install type

Tags: software-installation

As the title says, when I go through the installation, choose language --> keyboard layout --> full install/light install --> then where it usually gives you the option to install along side of windows, wipe disk, or advanced options..it actually just brings me directly to advanced options. I get no other choice. Also, within those options nothing seems to work for me and it isn't showing the actual space I have. What I would like is to completely wipe windows and install Ubuntu. I'm using an Acer Aspire on windows 11.

Comment: If you are "using Windows11" while the Ubuntu installaer is running, it must be a virtual machine, and so you can't wipe Windows.

Comment: Perhaps not a good idea to get rid of Windows if later you'll need it for some reason -or- you're under the (very) wrong impression that Wine is a universal panacea for running any Windows software. That said, if you really want to install Ubuntu only and the installer isn't recognizing correctly the drives that almost always is because some not yet compatible drive mode is selected in UEFI. Make sure to select AHCI -> Please note Windows will NOT boot after that but then you should be able to use the drive to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Nope, getting rid of windows on this machine is fine as I have others. Thank you, I will work on this next week. Happy 4th!

Comment: Do you have good backups? Did you use Windows to shrink the NTFS partition and turn off Windows fast startup/hibernation? Is drive set for AHCI, not RAID nor Intel RST? Then are you using Something Else install option? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2470817 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2468820